# Java: How do I return only objects of one parameter type from a List that contains more parameter types?

Tags: java, generics

I have this List that stores objects of type Team (sport teams) and I want to display the ranking of all teams of the same type:

```
static List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
```

Team class is generic, it accept  parameter types of some clases like: Fotbal, Basketball, etc.

With the following method I wish to display the ranks of teams of one type, for ex. to display all fotbal teams ranking:

```
static  void classament() {
        Collections.sort(Championship.teams);
        for (Team i : teams) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
     }
```

In this state the method return all teams irrespective of the type of sport.

This is my Team class declaration:

```
public class Team<T extends Player  > extends Championship implements Comparable<Team<T>>{

}
```

Comment: [edit] your question and post code for class `Team`

Comment: @Abra I'm trying to find a better question formula ... I have post the Team class declaraltion

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use the instanceof keyword like this:

```
if (team instanceof BasketballTeam) {
    System.out.println(team);
}
```

and this would work. But maybe a team should just be a generic object with an `enum` field storing its type? Then you could compare it with

```
if (team.getType() == BASEBALL)
```

Comment: If a different team type really needs different behavior, this can be done using the [strategy pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern)

Comment: It give this error: cannot cast 'genericType.Team' to 'genericType.FootbalPlayer . I have tryied to make the method generic but without success.